# Typescript array map union

Tags: typescript

I'm try to map over array that contains union of types but typescript marks my code as error, i can't figure out how i can implement this correctly, can you explain what is going on and how i can fix it ?

```
interface x {
    name: string;
}

interface y {
    value: string;
}

const arr: (x | y)[] = [{ name: '1' }, { value: '2' }];
arr.map(item => {
    console.log(item.name); // error here
})
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20x%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20y%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%3A%20(x%20%7C%20y)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20name%3A%20'1'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20value%3A%20'2'%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0Aarr.map(item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(item.name)%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array can contain either `x` or `y` you need to type guard for each of those scenarios. For example here you could use an `in` type guard:

```
interface x {
    name: string;
}

interface y {
    value: string;
}

const arr: (x | y)[] = [{ name: '1' }, { value: '2' }];
arr.map(item => {
    if ('name' in item) {
        console.log(item.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Comment: If you can, please edit the question to include the faulty code (either you or @ЕвгенийЛитвиненко); otherwise the question is off-topic.